# What is the memory layout of a vector of arrays?

Tags: arrays, rust

Are variables of type `Vec<[f3; 5]>` stored as one contiguous array (of `Vec::len() * 5 * sizeof(f32)` bytes) or is it stored as a `Vec` of pointers?

Answer (score 12):

The contents of a `Vec<T>` is, regardless of `T`, a single heap allocation, of `self.capacity() * std::mem::size_of::<T>()` bytes. (`Vec` overallocates—that’s the whole point of `Vec<T>` instead of `Box<[T]>`—so it’s the capacity, not the length, that matter in this calculation.) The actual `Vec<T>` itself takes three words ([24 bytes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20std%3A%3Amem%3A%3Asize_of%3A%3A%3CVec%3C%5Bf32%3B%205%5D%3E%3E())%3B%0A%7D&version=stable) on a 64-bit machine).

`[f32; 5]` is just a chunk of memory containing five 32-bit floating-point numbers, with no indirection; this comes to twenty bytes (hence [`std::mem::size_of::<[f32; 5]>() == 20`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20std%3A%3Amem%3A%3Asize_of%3A%3A%3C%5Bf32%3B%205%5D%3E())%3B%0A%7D&version=stable)).

Comment: Thanks. But `Vec<Vec<T>>` would be stored as a `Vec` of pointers right?

Comment: A `Vec<Vec<T>>` would have a series of tightly packed 3-word structs. One of those words would be a pointer. The other two are the capacity and length.

Comment: What about alignment? How big is the heap for `Vec<bool>`, `Vec<u8>` (is it equal to capacity), `Vec<(u8, u8)>`, `Vec<[u8; 3]>`?

Comment: @ArtemGr: what I said is precise.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Precise, but not reduntant. For the point to properly come across it have to be enlarged with examples and rehashings, sometimes. So, no alignment for the members I take it? (p.s. example of a similar explanation for C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13284631/257568). Still, the structs seem to be padded (http://is.gd/YbS3Nj) so sometimes the members of a `Vec<Struct>` will appear to be aligned.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Why `Vec` cares about http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.min_align_of.html there http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.map_in_place?