# What is the memory layout of a vector of vectors?

Tags: vector, rust

I know that some part of the vector (the actual data) is stored in the heap, while some data (a struct containing the length, capacity and pointer to the actual data in heap) is stored on the stack.

What about a vector of vectors (i.e the elements of the vector are other vectors, e.g. a vector of strings)? What parts of this outer container vector are stored in the heap and on thee stack? What about the individual inner elements?

Comment: what do you think ?

Comment: I think that the struct parts of the inner vectors are stored in the heap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that a `Vec` (the struct containing pointer, length and capacity) is *always* stored on the stack. You can move any type (excluding self-referential ones, which can't be moved) from the stack to the heap, by putting it in a `Box`, `Vec` or other heap-using smart pointer. Just consider a straightforward type like `i64`: it might be stored on the stack (or in a register if the compiler so chooses), but if you write `vec![7i64]`, you have an `i64` stored on the heap and the only thing left on the stack is the `Vec` itself (a pointer plus length and capacity).

With this analogy, it's not hard to see that the same applies for `String`: it *can* be on the stack, but you can put it on the heap by creating a `Vec<String>`. Therefore, if you have a `Vec<String>` with length 100, there are *101* independent heap allocations: one owned by the `Vec` and one owned by each of the `String`s.

### See also

- [If I make a struct and put it in a vector, does it reside on the heap or the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641728/if-i-make-a-struct-and-put-it-in-a-vector-does-it-reside-on-the-heap-or-the-sta)
- [What is the memory layout of a vector of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374179/what-is-the-memory-layout-of-a-vector-of-arrays)

Comment: What do you mean by the "self referential" ones?

Comment: @Satoshi Values that contain a reference to themselves or part of themselves are "self-referential". These values cannot be moved because moving one to a different memory location could invalidate the reference. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/3650362) has more information.